# EAGLE schematic - capacitors and resistors all incorrectly connect to each other in BOARD

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I'm relatively new to EAGLE and after watching tutorials I am trying to design a small board with (eventually) 16 low pass filters.

This is the schematic view, I am trying to make a low pass filter - ground, through capacitor, into the resistor. When I turn this into board view, it looks like the next picture which I believe is incorrect.

[image: This is the schematic view, I am trying to make a low pass filter - ground, through capacitor, into the resistor. When I turn this into board view, it looks like the next picture which I believe is incorrect.]

This is what the Board view looks like which seems wrong to me as all the capacitors are connected, as are all the resistors. But not to each other.

[image: This is what the Board view looks like which seems wrong to me as all the capacitors are connected, as are all the resistors. But not to each other.]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Eagle but to me it looks like you shorted all the capacitors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do wire both terminals of the capacitors together, they will be shorted out.

Notice how the green line connects both ends of the capacitors?

[image: Shorted]

If I were you, I would delete all of the signals in your schematic, rotate the caps vertically, placed above the ground terminals. Then place the resistors vertically above the capacitors.

Join them together with the wire tool making sure to end your wire on the pins themselves - don't draw a wire under the capacitor, the connection point is at the ends of the pins.

You can also draw one resistor/capacitor/GND, connect it up, and then group and copy/paste rather than drawing each one individually.

Also make sure to name your nets using the name tool on a wire. That way if you find any net called N$# you know you have a section of schematic where you haven't specifically named a wire. It also means you can more easily tell what each airwire is in the layout by checking its name.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about the green wire, thanks for pointing it out.  I am assuming by signals, you mean the green net wires?

I've fixed up the schematic, and in the board view the arrangement is correct, but it still groups all the resistors and solder pads next to each other, but it looks like a mess because the signal lines just go over each other -  is this normal for EAGLE?

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @ShivH correct.